# Custom API Access Policies and API Gateways

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, kong

I need some help in clearing out some doubts. I have been playing around with Kong and Amazon API Gateway but could not understand how to get my custom ACL working with these API Gateways.

Let me try to explain with an example:

**Currently:**

I have all ACLs mapped to API endpoints and verbs, I pick from MySQL DB (for different group of users) and store it in redis server and every API call check user's access rights from redis and allow / disallow endpoints.

**With API Gateway:**

With API Gateway, I can easily validate the user and pass on the auth token but I couldn't find a way to pass more data to gateway so gateway can check the authentication + ACL policy without coming back to auth server.

Kong has ACL plugin but could not find proper information on it.

Amazon API Gateway has custom authorizer option and option to pass policy via Lambda function but again, I am not sure if Lambda function can accept my custom ACL or not.

Did anyone here face this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't do this via a Custom Authorizer. Custom Authorizers are just Lambda functions that you write to authorize requests via any method you want. So you would create a Custom Authorizer Lambda function that verifies the request by comparing it to the data in your Redis server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Gateway custom authorizers which were developed for this exact type of use-case. You would simply implement the custom authorizer function to query your MySQL datastore and return an appropriate IAM policy for your API based on the user token.

In addition, API Gateway provides a caching layer for authorizer decisions, so you may not need redis at all. Just have your authorizer query your database directly, and set an appropriate cache TTL on your authorizer.

Please see:

[Customer Authorizer developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html)

[Customer Authorizer examples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints)

Thanks,
Ryan